# jQuery html manipulation

Tags: jquery, html, dom

```
<div class="row categories">
    <div class="span3 category">
        <a href="#" class="delete"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 category">
        <a href="#" class="delete"></a> <!-- user clicks this one -->
    </div>
    <div class="span3 category">
        <a href="#" class="delete"></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row categories">
    <div class="span3 category">
        <a href="#" class="delete"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 category">
        <a href="#" class="delete"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 category">
        <a href="#" class="delete"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a simplified sample of some html I am trying to manipulate with jQuery. When the user clicks delete the category is removed and then I want to rearrange the category divs so that the rows are filled from the top down.

To give an example: If the user clicks the delete that is labeled by the comment in the html above then I want to reshuffle the category divs so that the top row has three category divs in and the second row only has two in - this needs to work for any number of rows.

I have tried a few things but am not getting anywhere - I feel like I am missing some essential principle of DOM manipulation.

I have tried collecting all the category divs up as one object and then wrapping them in the relevant row tags but I get lots of "#DivElement does not have XXX property errors". I have tried rebuilding the html from scratch but then I get lots of nasty event handler .bind problems (as I said, this is a simplified sample). The later is the closest I have got but it feels ugly and overly complicated.

I feel like collecting up the category divs and then rewrapping them is the way to go but I really don't know ...

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please post some of the code you have tried so far! (also a jsFiddle)

Comment: Just have an UL element, and then float its LI's. That will make sure that each row is completely filled. (For this to work, the LI's should have equal dimensions.)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: sadly that breaks Twitter bootstraps responsiveness - nice idea though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a wrapper element (*with `id="container"` in my example*) try

```
var container = $('#container');
container.on('click','.delete', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel the click
    $(this).closest('.category').remove(); // remove clicked category

    var elements = container.find('.category').detach(); // get all .category elements
    container.empty().append(elements); // clear container and re-append only the category elements
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i+=3) {
      elements.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='row categories'></div>"); // wrap them every 3 categories..
    }
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/f47bJ/2/

Comment: This seems to work like a charm, there wasn't an overall container but adding one in has done the trick - I think this was the method my brain was try to grasp but couldn't quite get to - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this code. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RpPEx/)

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
var next = $(this).parents(".categories").next();
    if(next ){
      var copyfrmnext = next .find(".category:first");
    $(this).parent().parent().append( copyfrmnext );
   }
    $(this).parent().remove();

});
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesnt seem to work for more than 2 rows - if you delete from row 1 with 3 rows total the row 2 just gets smaller as the categories don't filter up from 3

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6rFMy/2/)

```
$('.delete').on('click', function () {

    var _myRow = $(this).closest('.row');
    var _nextCategory = _myRow.next('.row').find('.category').first();

    $(this).closest('.category').remove();

    _myRow.append(_nextCategory );
});​
```

Comment: quote from question **"this needs to work for any number of rows"**, this answer will not work correctly for more than two rows (*it needs to re-arrange all following rows..*)